# How to ask to change office without a danger to get fired

Tags: international

I'm working in a company that has offices in several countries. I moved to this country for this work. However, this country has appeared to be unbearable for me. Very few people speak English outside of my workplace (and even in the office people are reluctant to speak English other than for work). Most foreigners are students, and I befriended some, but they graduated and left. I don't have time to learn a new language. Also living conditions, services, environment etc. are not so good.

I want to either move back to my home country where this company has offices, or to some other country where they have offices. The problem is, if I stay in my current team, I will have to work 100% remotely or I will have to switch teams (doing the same kind of job but different product or different tools), I would be perfectly happy with both options.

Can I ask this without being labeled as a next person to get fired? Is the only way to be safe just to apply to other jobs in countries where I want to live?

Comment: It seems you are leaving out information. Why would you get fired? If they have offices in multiple countries, they certainly have a way to apply for internal transfers, don't they?

Comment: My work is currently non-remote job in one team. If I express interest in leaving that team and changing to something they don't want me to change, it is possible that they don't want to employ me because I don't want to do what they want me to do, right?

Comment: Is it common for your colleagues to switch teams? Even if it is for less extreme reasons, does it happen often in your company?

Comment: In between the teams in one office, very common. In between the countries, I don't know anybody.

Comment: How long have you spend in this country and this role? Is there any other team in this country which has people in other locations?

Comment: Around 1 year, teams need a lot of cooperation with people in other countries, but the teams itself are usually small, 4-5 people and working in a same country.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ask this without being labeled as a next person to get fired?

Asking about other opportunities should not be grounds for being fired, but it could mean that you are viewed as not fully committed which could affect you in other ways. **If you actually get fired because you asked about other opportunities then you may be able to pursue a case for unfair dismissal.**

I have experienced employees asking about this kind of thing before. If you trust your manager then it is easier to ask, and if you ask carefully then you can reduce the risk of being labeled. At the same time, if you really are not happy where you are then **the outcome where you remain in your current job and country seems like a poor outcome for you anyway**.

If you do bring this up then you should consider what you would accept/ask for in terms of relocation costs, visa sponsorship etc. It may be easier to move between countries if the company doesn't have to foot the bill for this.

> Is the only way to be safe just to apply to other jobs in countries where I want to live?

No, if the company you work for is focused on their people, and you trust your manager then you can raise lateral moves safely. If that is not your situation then yes.

You may find that starting to apply for other jobs in the country you want to move to gives you more confidence to raise the possibility of moving within the same company, knowing that you have realistic alternatives.